# Gist oneboxing is broken since the recent changes to gist

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, onebox

GitHub recently made some changes to gist. It's more awesome now but unfortunately oneboxing of gists is now broken.

[image: meow]

Comment: For a moment I thought that's what you get when trying to onebox gist!

Comment: It *should* be. Derpy cats are awesome.

Comment: Why did you use Gist on SE? \*suspicious.grumpy.old.man.look\*

Comment: Because dumping lots of code in chat kills kittens!

Comment: Oh Chat! ...hey, that tag wasn't there before! That explains why I don't find it on the frontpage anymore....uuuhhh...I think I'll leave now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up this report.

I've done some other fixing on gists today and I believe everything works as it should.

Comment: Can you check again? Because it doesn't work anymore :(